# Weird characters in html text. Inserting `;` inside a variable string

Tags: python, html

I am seeing weird characters while using html text in python. Its just this one name which is inserting weird character `;` into it.

My html text looks like this:

```
text="<font name=Helvetica color=white size=8>Name:  </font><font name=Helvetica-Bold color=white size=8>%s </font>" % name
```

where `name = 'A&B CDE F.'` But the output is: `'Name: A&B; CDE F.'`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Can you add more context?

Comment: Hi! Sorry I did not give much info. I am using Paragraph from reportlab and using this text to draw on the PDF. Turtlefight's solution below solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when interpolating variables into html strings / templates, you need to properly escape the string.

The Ampersand Character is used in html for [character escapes](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes), so you need to replace it with `&amp;`.

For Python 2 you can use `cgi.escape`:

```
import cgi
text="<font>%s</font>" % cgi.escape(name)
```

For Python 3 you can choose between `cgi.escape` and `html.escape`:

```
import html
text="<font>%s</font>" % html.escape(name)
```

Also check out the [python wiki page for html escapes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml) for a comprehensive overview of the different html escape functions in python :)